# how to get list of the cities from certain country

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get list of the cities of Ukraine for example.

I tried next code:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P17 wd:Q212.
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q515
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

But it only outputs weird 3 results. I think i'm doing something wrong

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P17 wd:Q212.
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: @AKSW Thank you, its working. What does star * mean in your example?

Comment: well, `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*` is a so-called *property path* - it basically means, "everything that is a city or some subtype of city". Technically, * means zero or more steps on the path and `wdt:279` is the subclass relation of Wikidata similar to `rdfs:subClassOf`